# How does char* map to a string

Tags: c

In C, the character * makes a variable a pointer. Thus one would assume that some variable char* would be a pointer to a char, but somehow it can become an array of chars. How is this possible?

Comment: Explained in any C book.

Comment: It's not limited to `char*`. An `int*` can very well point to an element in an array of `int`s.

Comment: @BoPersson: True. But `char*` stands out more because there are dozens of standard library functions that take `char*` pointers to strings as arguments.

Answer (score 4):

The terms "string" and "pointer to a string" are defined in the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf), 7.1.1 paragraph 1:

> A *string* is a contiguous sequence of characters
>   terminated by and including the first null character. The
>   term *multibyte string* is sometimes used instead to
>   emphasize special processing given to multibyte characters
>   contained in the string or to avoid confusion with a wide
>   string. A *pointer to a string* is a pointer to its initial
>   (lowest addressed) character. The *length of a string*
>   is the number of bytes preceding the null character and
>   the *value of a string* is the sequence of the values of
>   the contained characters, in order.

(The link is to `n1570.pdf`, the most recent publicly available draft of the 2011 ISO C standard.)

There is no string type in C. A string is a data format, not a data type. A string is usually stored in an array of `char`.

As for a *pointer to a string*, as the standard says that's a pointer to its first character. C generally deals with arrays via pointers to the arrays' individual elements. Pointer arithmetic lets us advance a pointer through successive elements of an array. (Some languages let you deal with arrays as whole objects; you can't easily do that in C.)

Some sources will tell you that arrays are really pointers, or that a `char*` is a string. Those sources are wrong. Arrays are not pointers, and pointers are not arrays. What causes this confusion is that arrays are generally manipulated using pointers, and a special language rule says that an array expression is "converted" to a pointer to the array's initial element. But that conversion (actually a compile-time adjustment) applies only to array *expressions*, not to array or pointer objects. Another source of confusion is that array parameters are "adjusted" to a pointer type; for example `void foo(int n[10])` really means `int foo(int *n)`.

A `char*` never "becomes" an array of `char`s, but code that wants to manipulate an array of `char`s will do so via a `char*` pointer that can be advanced to point to successive elements of that array. And a `char[]` array may or may not contain a *string*, depending on whether it contains the required terminating null character `'\0'`.

Recommended reading: [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com), particularly section 6.

Comment: I think that another cause of confusion may be that array types are adjusted to appropriate pointer types in function declarations, so that `void func(char arr[]);`, `void func(char arr[10]);`, and `void func(char *arr);` are all equivalent.

Comment: @DavidBowling: Good point, I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Compared to many languages, C has a fairly weak type system. And even when more-strongly-typed possibilities exist, such as `enum`, they often aren't used.

As a result, when dealing with a C library, you need to figure out what *conventions* a given API is using, not just its signature. Many libraries are at least fairly consistent internally.

The compiler converts the `"abc"` syntax to a reference to some unnamed array, like `char __anonymous[] = {'a', 'b', 'c', '\0'};`. So that is a very common convention.

Note that using `const` appropriately will make many conventions easier to follow. The only reason string literals *aren't* `const` is because that keyword didn't exist in the early days of C; it is still undefined behavior to modify them.

Comment: This is not the truth. They are constans as they are kept in the RO parts of memory / disk

Comment: @PeterJ_01: They might or might not be, depending on the implementation.

Comment: You used `const` in your anonymous array declaration. C string literals, as you point out, are not `const`. The string literal `"hello"` refers to an anonymous object of type `char[6]`.

Comment: Modifying a string literal isn't exactly illegal. It has undefined behavior. Commonly the result is some kind of run-time trap, but it could also successfully modify the array object. (The tcc compiler has writable string literals.)